# In "The Accidental", was it really Amber who did this?

Tags: ali-smith, the-accidental

**Warning: contains unmarked spoilers.**

Ali Smith's *The Accidental* is about the Smart family (Eve, Michael, Magnus, and Astrid) and a woman, Amber, who seemingly appears out of nowhere at their holiday home and has a dramatic effect on each of their lives. The book is split into twelve main parts: a "beginning", "middle", and "end" for each of Astrid, Magnus, Michael, and Eve respectively.

After Amber leaves at the end of the "middle" section, the Smarts return to their real home to find it bare: thieves have completely ransacked the place. The implication is that Amber was to blame:

> Months later he remembered that she knew
>   where the house keys were kept, after this game–
>   in the bedside cabinet. Months later, too,
>   he thought about the wanting her with shame
>   and not a little wryness, like a clue
>   right under his own nose, a clue that came
>   and went and told him exactly what he needed,
>   plain as abc, and he’d refused to read it.
>
> <sub>-- middle, Michael</sub>

> The real world was elsewhere, like she was.
>
> Imagine her, systematically emptying things room by room, shifting them through the front door and across the pavement into a van in the dead of night. She was in league with someone, a man, surely. She had to be. She'd need someone to help move the heavier things; you'd need someone to help you clean up afterwards.
>
> <sub>-- middle, Michael</sub>

But is there really enough evidence to say that Amber robbed them after she left, or could it have been a coincidence? Or is the point that it's supposed to be ambiguous and we can never know? Given the significance of all the character interactions in the book, I'm sure that whatever the answer to this question is, it will tie in metaphorically to the relationships that form the core of the story.

This is a significant question to ask, because the answer to it may change our view of Amber. Was she merely a thief taking advantage of the family, and her lasting influence on their lives an accident, or was she somehow sent by Providence, an odd stranger, as Eve is to the other family at the very end?

**Was Amber involved in the ransacking of the Smarts' home or not?**